# GameObject.SendMessage not working, how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sendmessage, gameobject

I'm trying to do a script that when the player pass by a item, it activates it's effect in the player.
But this error apears:
[image: SendMessage doubleSpeed has no receiver! UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()]
This is my code:
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Bonus : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collision.SendMessage(name, null, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

`

I already tried adding the

```
SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver
```

but it didn't work

Comment: you’re not sending a method name to call here, your name variable is null

Comment: the name variable is being set in the item inspector

Answer (score 0):

What the error is trying to tell you is:

On your `collision`'s `GameObject` there is no component attached that implements a method called whatever the value of `name` is (in your case `doubleSpeed`).

By default the option already is [`SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver.html), if there is none you get that error message.

> The receiving method can choose to ignore the argument by having zero parameters. If options is set to SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver an error is printed if the message is not picked up by any component.

If you want to ignore the case where there is no receiver you would rather pass in [`SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver.html)

---

In general instead of using `SendMessage` at all rather get your component and call the method directly

Comment: I was using the get component, but then it had a script for each item, so i wanted to make only one for all, i noticed the SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver a little bit later i sent the question, but my internet was bad so i could not delete it, but thank you :)

Comment: Use a common base class/interface then ?